# Proving that point of intersection of diagonals of trapezium lies on the line passing through the midpoint of parallel sides?

Tags: vectors

Can someone tell me the steps to solve this problem?

> Prove by vector method that the point of intersection of diagonals of
>   trapezium lies on the line passing through the midpoint of parallel
>   sides.

I assumed the ratio of division of diagonals at intersection point as $a:1$ and $b:1$ and wrote the position vectors of the intersection point in terms of $a$ and $b$.But i'm getting too many variables.Any easier way out?

Answer (score 1):

[image]
$$\vec{OM}=\frac 12 (\vec{OB}+\vec{OC});  \vec{ON}=\frac12(\vec{OA}+\vec{OD})$$
$\vec{OB}=k\vec{OA}$ and $\vec{OC}=k_1\vec{OD}$
$$\triangle BOC \sim \triangle AOD \Rightarrow \frac{OB}{OA}=\frac{OC}{OD}.$$
Then $k=k_1$.

Now $$\vec{OM}=\frac 12 (\vec{OB}+\vec{OC})=\frac12(k\vec{OA}+k\vec{OD})=$$
$$=k\frac12(\vec{OA}+\vec{OD})=k\vec{ON}$$
$\vec{OM}=k\vec{ON} \Rightarrow O,M,N -$ point on a straight line.

Comment: You must've misread the question: the specified intersection point is that of the trapezium's diagonals—not its non-parallel sides. [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4064489/21813)'s an answer to the question though.